# Faster way to farm ender-lilies

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've got 5 ender lilies from a dungeon then wanted to farm then. I know end stone significantly speeds up the progress, bonemeal, the Sprinkler and the Thaumcraft hoe of growth kill the lilies.Is there any way to speed up the growing of ender lilies not including end stone.

I'm playing direwolf20 1.6.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for Ender Lilies are actually extremely complicated, as it turns out.  See [this FTB Wiki page](http://ftbwiki.org/Ender-Lily_Seeds) for a comprehensive description of how they work, at least in version 1.0.3c.

Short version:

> 1. If you have reliable access to enough Ender Core blocks, then always grow Ender-Lily crops on that.  Otherwise, if you have access to End Stone, definitely grow on that.
> 2. Only half of the growth stages can advance to the next stage at any given point in time, and they're staggered so you won't be able to grow a crop twice in a row (except if you happens to try at the boundary between sliding windows, which is always at a sunrise when growing on anything but Ender Core).
> 3. Using a [Watering Can](http://ftbwiki.org/Watering_Can) on the crop for a few seconds should be enough to force growth if it's possible.  Otherwise, the randomness of block updates could possibly cause you to miss growth during a time when it's possible for the crop to grow.

In other words, this crop forces you to wait a minimum amount of in-game time after planting before you can harvest it.  For a crop planted on End Stone in the Overworld on a world that's hitting 20 ticks every second, the absolute best-case scenario outside of using Ender Core (which is very expensive) is that you plant it just before sunrise (50% of the time) and use the Watering Can, then it grows immediately, then sunrise happens and you use the Watering Can again and it grows again, leaving only 5 more growth stages to go through; sleep immediately when possible and use the Watering Can right after sunrise; do this until you can harvest it.  All of this will take slightly more than **50 minutes** ("slightly more" = it takes a few seconds to go to sleep each time).

If you have the time, read the [FTB Wiki page](http://ftbwiki.org/Ender-Lily_Seeds) for a more comprehensive explanation about what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

In Ars Magica 2, there's the sigil of nature's bounty. These should accelerate the growth as well.

Comment: not a fan of ars magica 2 :(

Comment: @LFM doesn't stop you from making just the sigil and the stand

Comment: ok but i dont now how any of ars magica works maybe show a link to  a youtube vid to hel me

Comment: Direwolf20's mod spotlight is very helpful, the basics are explained in part 1 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rTtTye1NkU)
The Arcane Compendium contains all the info you need.

You're probably going to need an essence refiner, which is explained at 9:45 in part 2 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_frf_SlaE4)

Answer (score 3):

Thaumcraft grow lamps affect every thing I've paired them with, but I've not personally tried them with ender lilies.  The lamps are not trivial to discover or get setup and running, but it sounds like you've got the hoe of growth already, so it may be worth trying.

Good luck, and if you give it a try, let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

Ender Lilies are allergic to bone-meal; they will actually go back one stage when bone meal is used on them. Same happens when Hoe of Growth is used, or any bone-meal based method such as a Sprinkler. Its growth is coded to be tied to the sun and moon movements.

Comment: so does that mean no sun or moon no growth?

Answer (score 1):

There are items called 'Lily pads of Fertility' they serve the same purpose as a 'Watering can' however they are placed in water adjacent to the crop and are completely passive.

Another thing that could be combined with the lily pads is a 'Sprinkler' from Extra Utilities, it requires some sort of water input, but it uses very little.

Apart from those I don't know of many ways to increase crop growth.

Comment: I dont have Xeno's Reliquary with the modpack so the lily pads wont work :(

Comment: the sprinkler is acting like bonemeal and getting rid of the plants

Comment: this would be manual, but have you tried the watering can?

Comment: yes and wouldnt work

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then, I haven't had much experience with ender lilies. I do some experimentation and get back to you.

Comment: ok well you tried :)\

Answer (score 1):

if the growth of the ender lilies is bound to the sun and moon movements try to plant them in a mystcraft age with a faster day cycle it is modified with the length page

Answer (score 0):

Try planting the ender lilies on ender cores. They grow insanely fast on them. They don't require end stone to make, but it does require some ender pearls and enchanted books.

Answer (score 0):

Don't farm ender lilies; farm enderweed from AgriCraft (but you will need to have this mod in your mod pack!!).

Use crop mutation to get the seeds, then use a photogenic insulator (and other machines) to automate ender pearl production. Here is my setup.

[image]

Niter comes from pulverizing sandstone (renewable), pulverized coal comes from an automated tree farm elsewhere, and the pulverized ore input is from another giant machine I've built elsewhere.

Comment: I tried your suggestion on FTB Ozone 2 / MC 1.7.10 and this does not work, the Phytogenic Insolator does not allow ender lilies to be inserted. It may have been a specific customization for the modpack you were using?

Comment: @DaleMahalko Yea I noticed that as well when trying to do this in a different world. Must be a setting somewhere. Off the top of my head, maybe if you have Botania you can try using dispensers to plant ender lilies and then automate harvesting them somehow (maybe drum of the wild connected with a timed mana burst). IIRC they need complete darkness and a LOT of time to grow, but if your farm is big enough you'll get tons of yield.

Comment: @DaleMahalko Quick correction. It's been a while since I wrote this so I forgot some of the details. The above setup doesn't explain how to farm enter lilies, it explains how to farm enderweed from agricraft. If you don't have agricraft try the botania method (I think this worked for me in the past, but it's been a while).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late to the party but ActuallyAdditions' greenhouse glass works a treat with Ender Lillies on End Stone. I harvest them twice per minecraft day and that's not paying much attention to them. I could probably harvest them more. I'm not far enough into my world to test a harvester with them yet but hope this helps someone.